# remove node options from admin area when creating nodes

Tags: theming, 6

where creating nodes (node/add/content-type) bellow body box there are some options related to comments, author, menu and ..

How can I hide those options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a module and implement **[hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)**.

Then, in the **$form** array, **unset** the array index(es) containing the parts you don't want your users to see and configure.

ps: I advice you do the above by permissions. So, those array indexes are unset for specific roles not all roles which would include user#1

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway by editing node core module?

Comment: Not adviceable to hack the core. Extending hooks is the only adviceable way to alter default functionality

Comment: Can you please just tell me which file to edit ?